# How to get a document id by giving input of its fields?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want doc uid by giving input its fields which are unique. For example a collection of email ids is created for every email there is unique uid for it. Now by giving email id as an input I want to retrieve the doc uid which contains the email id.

Comment: That sounds like a task for a query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries If you're having trouble making it work, please edit your question to show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getDocId()async{
  String email='youremail';//your email over here as an input
  QuerySnapshot snapshot=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('blogs').where('emailId',isEqualTo: email).limit(1).get();
  String docId=snapshot.docs.first.id;//now docId contains the id of that document
}
```

You can use a querysnapshot and apply query to get the docId of the document associated with the email.